# Codeigneter 404 error always shown

Tags: codeigniter

Hello I am newbie to codeigneter and start building a simple website for my store,
the home page has been made successfully without any problem.

when i started to create the category controller I got 404 error all time.

First I have created a db moder as shown below

```
class Db_model extends CI_Model {

 public function __construct()
 {
  $this->load->database();
 }
}
```

The category controller is as shown below:

```
class Category extends CI_Controller {
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('db_model');
 }

 public function index()
 {
  $catid = $this->uri->segment(2);
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = ".$catid." ORDER BY seq DESC");
  $this->load->library('parser');
  $cat = array(
   'company_entries' => $query->result_array()
            );
        $this->load->view('header');
  $this->parser->parse('category', $cat);
  $this->load->view('footer');

 }

}
```

I have added this line to routes.php

```
$route['category/(:any)'] = 'category/$1';
```

the url must be like

```
"http://localhost/category/catid"
```

.htacess file is as below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

the error 404 is still showing any solutions please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace your `router.php` code with the following:

> $route['category/(:any)'] = 'category/index/$1';

**Explanation:**

As of your current routing for url `http://localhost/category/catid` codeigniter looks for method named `catid` in your category controller, which doesn't exists. By replacing the rule we are telling codeigniter to call the `index` function of your `category` controller.